# SQL query with UNION ALL and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to get the result to be like

```
**PROTOCOL_NAME GREEN   AMBER   RED**
DP1               1       1       1
```

but I am getting the result like below:

```
**PROTOCOL_NAME  STATUS    CNT**
DP1            GREEN      1
DP1            AMBER      1
DP1            RED        1
```

Can you please help correcting the query?

```
select protocol_name,status,sum(qty) from 
(select mp.protocol_name, teh.status as status, count(mp.protocol_id) as qty
from t_execution_hourly teh, m_protocol mp, m_protocol_category mpc, m_service ms, m_domain md, m_environment me
where ms.service_id = 3
and md.domain_name = 'FlexA'
and me.environment_name = 'PROD'
and mpc.protocol_category in ('F5','DP','TOMCAT')
and me.environment_id = mp.environment_id
and md.domain_id= mp.domain_id
and ms.service_id = mp.service_id
and mpc.protocol_category_id = mp.protocol_category_id
and mp.protocol_id = teh.protocol_id
and teh.status = 'GREEN' 
and to_date(teh.EXECUTION_DATE) = to_date(sysdate)--between sysdate and (sysdate - 1)
group by  teh.status,mp.protocol_name

union all 

select mp.protocol_name, teh.status as status, count(mp.protocol_id) as qty
from t_execution_hourly teh, m_protocol mp, m_protocol_category mpc, m_service ms, m_domain md, m_environment me
where ms.service_id = 3
and md.domain_name = 'FlexA'
and me.environment_name = 'PROD'
and mpc.protocol_category in ('F5','DP','TOMCAT')
and me.environment_id = mp.environment_id
and md.domain_id= mp.domain_id
and ms.service_id = mp.service_id
and mpc.protocol_category_id = mp.protocol_category_id
and mp.protocol_id = teh.protocol_id
and teh.status = 'AMBER' 
and to_date(teh.EXECUTION_DATE) = to_date(sysdate)--between sysdate and (sysdate - 1)
group by  teh.status, mp.protocol_name

union all

select mp.protocol_name, teh.status as status, count(mp.protocol_id) as qty
from t_execution_hourly teh, m_protocol mp, m_protocol_category mpc, m_service ms, m_domain md, m_environment me
where ms.service_id = 3
and md.domain_name = 'FlexA'
and me.environment_name = 'PROD'
and mpc.protocol_category in ('F5','DP','TOMCAT')
and me.environment_id = mp.environment_id
and md.domain_id= mp.domain_id
and ms.service_id = mp.service_id
and mpc.protocol_category_id = mp.protocol_category_id
and mp.protocol_id = teh.protocol_id  
and teh.status = 'RED' 
and to_date(teh.EXECUTION_DATE) = to_date(sysdate)--between sysdate and (sysdate - 1)
group by  teh.status, mp.protocol_name
)t
group by status,protocol_name
```

Comment: Pleas reformat the result since it's not clear what exact result is expected...

Answer (score 2):

Your query is way overcomplicated, if I'm reading it correctly.  You don't need to "union" these together.  You can just select all of them and use `group by`.  Try this:

```
select mp.protocol_name, 
       sum(case when status = 'GREEN' then 1 else 0 end) as green,
       sum(case when status = 'AMBER' then 1 else 0 end) as amber,
       sum(case when status = 'RED' then 1 else 0 end) as red
from t_execution_hourly teh, m_protocol mp, m_protocol_category mpc, m_service ms, m_domain md, m_environment me
where ms.service_id = 3
and md.domain_name = 'FlexA'
and me.environment_name = 'PROD'
and mpc.protocol_category in ('F5','DP','TOMCAT')
and me.environment_id = mp.environment_id
and md.domain_id= mp.domain_id
and ms.service_id = mp.service_id
and mpc.protocol_category_id = mp.protocol_category_id
and mp.protocol_id = teh.protocol_id  
and teh.status in ('AMBER', 'RED', 'GREEN'
and to_date(teh.EXECUTION_DATE) = to_date(sysdate)--between sysdate and (sysdate - 1)
group by mp.protocol_name;
```

You should also learn to use modern join syntax, using an `on` clause.  But that is a different issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon, It fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your result are exactly what you are asking for.

```
select protocol_name,status,sum(qty)
```

To get what you need you need to different query. Shortest path to get what you want is to split query into three parts, lets call them by their status. Then instead of union use subqueries:

```
select 
  (select count(mp.protocol_id) ... where status = 'GREEN') as green, 
  (select count(mp.protocol_id) ... where status = 'AMBER') as amber, 
  (select count(mp.protocol_id) ... where status = 'RED') as red
```